# servidor mysql tarda mucho en dar respuestas

Tags: mysql, vscode, ubuntu-server

tengo un servidor de MySQL (Ubuntu srv 20.04.5 versión MySQL 8.0.31 ), que tarda bastante en dar respuesta, cuando intento conectarme con el tiempo predefinido (5000 ms) me da error de conexión, pero cuando intento conectarme con 15000 ms, ya si que me deja, como si el tickrate del servidor (está en una maquina virtual ya que es para un tfg/ proyecto para una empresa y quiero primero hacerlo aislado y a continuación pasar la misma configuración a el "servidor cutre que va a tener")
[image: 5k tickrate]

[image: 15k tickrate]
esto pasa con un conector MySQL en vscode, workbenc
y toad, llevo un tiempo intentando solucionarlo pero sin solución, osea que he presupuesto que el error viene de parte del servidor.

también he probado con un túnel ssh, pero da el mismo error aunque me conecto con ssh a la maquina de por si todo el rato

si alguien me puede echar una mano lo agradecería, gracias de antemano :)